# how to grant accessibility permissions when developing macos app

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, accessibility

I am a beginner macOS app developer.

I am developing a macos app that requires accessibility permissions.

I have granted accessibility permissions in the system's Security & Privacy settings for

`/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test2-clnwpkszkajkbtfdwfzlmsovemod/Build/Products/Debug/test2.app`

`/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test2-clnwpkszkajkbtfdwfzlmsovemod/Build/Products/Debug/test2.app/Contents/MacOS/test2`

However, when I use `NSApplication.shared.isAccessibilityEnabled()` to check if the app has accessibility permissions, it still returns false.

Am I missing any other configuration?

my code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    func test() {
        let isAccessibilityEnabled = NSApplication.shared.isAccessibilityEnabled()
        print("isAccessibilityEnabled: \(isAccessibilityEnabled)")
        
        let script = """
        tell application "System Events"
            set frontApp to name of first application process whose frontmost is true
            tell process frontApp
                set windowName to name of front window
                display dialog "window：" & windowName
            end tell
        end tell
        """
        
        var error: NSDictionary?
        if let appleScript = NSAppleScript(source: script) {
            appleScript.executeAndReturnError(&error)
            if let error = error {
                print("script failed: \(error)")
            } else {
                print("script succeeded")
            }
        } else {
            print("Failed to create NSAppleScript object")
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear() {
            test()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

output:

```
isAccessibilityEnabled: false
script failed: {
    NSAppleScriptErrorAppName = "System Events";
    NSAppleScriptErrorBriefMessage = "Application isn\U2019t running.";
    NSAppleScriptErrorMessage = "System Events got an error: Application isn\U2019t running.";
    NSAppleScriptErrorNumber = "-600";
    NSAppleScriptErrorRange = "NSRange: {53, 57}";
}
2023-07-09 13:49:59.975348+0800 test2[97372:462728] [Window] Warning: Window SwiftUI.AppKitWindow 0x1037057f0 ordered front from a non-active application and may order beneath the active application's windows.
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `NSAppleScript` cannot be used if the app is sandboxed. And a SwiftUI view is the wrong place anyway to check for a system setting.